# Can't access internet after installing antivirus

Tags: windows-8.1, internet-connection, avg-antivirus

I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro - 64 bit. Today, I installed AVG Internet Security 2015 on my laptop, but afterwards, I can't access the internet. I use a WiFi connection, but after installation, my laptop is not connecting to any connection.

**Things I tried**:

1. Disabling firewall (both Windows and AVG's)
2. Temporarily disabling the antivirus

Can anyone please help me in this regard?

Comment: Are you getting an IP address?  `ipconfig` from a command line will tell you

Comment: Yes, i'm getting an IP address, internet works for a while when I reboot. But stops when AVG starts.

Comment: unistall AVG and see if the internet works?  If so, try reinstalling

Comment: @Keltari - I've tried that. It's definitely because of AVG. But I don't know how to make it work with AVG's firewall enabled.

Comment: Did you run the [Firewall Configuration Wizard](http://www.avg.com/eu-en/54051)?

Comment: Does the internet work with a **wired** connection?

Comment: @DavidPostill - I'm using WiFi and I've disabled the firewall in AVG, then also it's not working. It only works when I uninstall AVG.

Comment: Did you **run the Firewall Configuration Wizard**? Have you **tried a wired connection**?

Answer (score 1):

It appears your internet is trying to connect using the AVG driver. 
That usually gets installed when someone upgrades to the AVG paid version via `Upgrade` instead of `Update` on the free version.

Try this:

1. Right-click on your Wifi toolbar icon and choose `Connect to a network`.
2. Find your network, and right-click on it. Select `Status`.
3. Click `Properties` on on the Wireless Network Connection Status window.
4. A list of ticked boxes will appear. Untick the one that uses AVG and exit.

All should than be fixed. If it works, go back and uninstall the avg driver.